# Join dataframes based on partial string-match between columns

Tags: python, pandas, join, string-matching, partial

I have a dataframe which I want to compare if they are present in another df.

```
after_h.sample(10, random_state=1)

             movie           year   ratings
108 Mechanic: Resurrection   2016     4.0
206 Warcraft                 2016     4.0
106 Max Steel                2016     3.5
107 Me Before You            2016     4.5
```

I want to compare if the above movies are present in another df.

```
              FILM                   Votes
0   Avengers: Age of Ultron (2015)   4170
1   Cinderella (2015)                 950
2   Ant-Man (2015)                   3000 
3   Do You Believe? (2015)            350
4   Max Steel (2016)                  560
```

I want something like this as my final output:

```
    FILM              votes
0  Max Steel           560
```

Comment: You can join with `pd.merge()` if you convert the compound string column df2['FILM'] into its two component columns `movie_title (year)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given input dataframes `df1` and `df2`, you can use Boolean indexing via [`pd.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html). To align the format of the movie strings you need to first concatenate movie and year from `df1`:

```
s = df1['movie'] + ' (' + df1['year'].astype(str) + ')'

res = df2[df2['FILM'].isin(s)]

print(res)

               FILM  VOTES
4  Max Steel (2016)    560
```

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways:

1. get the row-indices for partial-matches: `FILM.startswith(title)` or `FILM.contains(title)`. Either of:

   `df1[ df1.movie.apply( lambda title: df2.FILM.str.startswith(title) ).any(1) ]`

   `df1[ df1['movie'].apply(lambda title: df2['FILM'].str.contains(title)).any(1) ]`

```
     movie      year      ratings
106  Max Steel  2016      3.5
```

2. Alternatively, **you can use `merge()` if you convert the compound string column df2['FILM'] into its two component columns `movie_title (year)`**.

.

```
# see code at bottom to recreate your dataframes
df2[['movie','year']] = df2.FILM.str.extract('([^\(]*) \(([0-9]*)\)')
# reorder columns and drop 'FILM' now we have its subfields 'movie','year'
df2 = df2[['movie','year','Votes']]
df2['year'] = df2['year'].astype(int)

df2.merge(df1)
       movie  year  Votes  ratings
0  Max Steel  2016    560      3.5
```

(Acknowledging much help from @user3483203 here and in Python chat room)

Code to recreate dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

dat1 = """movie           year   ratings
108  Mechanic: Resurrection   2016     4.0
206  Warcraft                 2016     4.0
106  Max Steel                2016     3.5
107  Me Before You            2016     4.5"""

dat2 = """FILM                   Votes
0   Avengers: Age of Ultron (2015)   4170
1   Cinderella (2015)                 950
2   Ant-Man (2015)                   3000
3   Do You Believe? (2015)            350
4   Max Steel (2016)                  560"""

df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(dat1), sep='\s{2,}', engine='python', index_col=0)
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(dat2), sep='\s{2,}', engine='python')
```

Comment: `df2[df1['movie'].apply(lambda movie_title: df2['FILM'].str.contains(movie_title)).any(0)]`

Comment: Partial matches may not be appropriate for sequels :)

Comment: @jpp: Teehee. Complain to Tom Cruise or George Lucas... Yes strictly, `df2['FILM']` is formatted and contains both the title and (year) in parentheses. I should show how if we fixed that up, we could do simple join on title.

Answer (score 0):

[smci](https://stackoverflow.com/users/202229/smci)'s option 1 is nearly there, the following worked for me:

```
df1['Votes'] = ''
df1['Votes']=df1['movie'].apply(lambda title: df2[df2['FILM'].str.startswith(title)]['Votes'].any(0))
```

*Explanation:*

Create a Votes column in df1

Apply a lambda to every movie string in df1

The lambda looks up df2, selecting all rows in df2 where Film starts with the movie title

Select the Votes column of the resulting subset of df2

Take the first value in this column with any(0)