# Merge two tables from names

Tags: python, pandas, string, merge

I have two table that has football players data and I will merge them from the name feature however one table has feature 'long_name' and other has 'short_name'. For example one player has name "Kevin Oghenetega Tamaraebi Bakumo-Abraham" in one table and "Tammy Abraham" in the other table as you can see they some times use kind of nickname.

I tried to use fuzzywuzzy library based on ratio of letters but it is not working as expected. any suggestion?

```
def find_best_match(name, choices):
    return process.extractOne(name, choices, scorer=fuzz.ratio)

# Apply the function to find the best match for each name in forwards
forwards['best_match'] = forwards['Player'].apply(lambda x: find_best_match(x, fifa_fows['long_name']))

# Extract the best matched names and merge again
forwards['best_name'] = forwards['best_match'].apply(lambda x: x[0] if x else None)
final_forwards = pd.merge(forwards, fifa_fows[['long_name', 'overall']], left_on='best_name', right_on='long_name', how='left')

# Drop intermediate columns
final_forwards = final_forwards.drop(['best_match', 'best_name'], axis=1)
```

Comment: place the dataframes text so that they can be reproduced and show expected result.

Comment: had this same issue with NFL. My best option was yes to use fuzzywuzzy to find the matches, then store those into a dictionary. Few things to keep in mind is a) find a threshold you are comfortable with; b) I had to write a little script to allow me to choose from a list if it was not a close enough match, and c) the option to insert manually by using free text. There is also the scenario that a name may never appear in both datasets, which you need to consider. If you are interested in that little script, shoot me an email jason.schvach@gmail.com and I'll talk you through it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using `str.contains` function to find partial matches:

```
str.contains("needle")
```

[Join dataframes based on partial string-match between columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52265419/join-dataframes-based-on-partial-string-match-between-columns)